# How do I access ENV from config/environment in an addon?

Tags: ember.js, ember-addon

This is a question that was asked by @dbendaou over on the [Ember Discord](https://discord.gg/emberjs)

---

What is the best way to access ENV from config/envirnoment in an addon?

I was thinking about `getOwner(this).lookup('config:environment')` but it doesn't work
neither does `import ENV from '../config/environment';`

Answer (score 1):

From addons, specifically, since your context doesn't define the environment, you need a slightly different API:

```
import { getOwner } from '@ember/application';

// ....
export default class MyAddonComponent extends Component {
  get env() {
    getOwner(this).resolveRegistration('config:environment')
  }
}
```

`import ENV from '../config/environment'` is an alias for `import ENV from '<app-name>/config/environment';` which, addons can't know what the `<app-name>` is.

Maybe related, because this has come up a number of times in the discord, is that this would also be how you get access to environment variables at runtime.
environment.js is a build-time file, so it has access to the node environment your app builds in and it outputs a JSON object for your app to consume.

For example:

```js
// <your-app>/config/environment.js

const MY_ENV_VAR = process.env;

module.exports = function (environment) {
  let ENV = {
     // ...
     MY_ENV_VAR,

  };

  return ENV;
}
```

Then, your addon can access `MY_ENV_VAR` via resolveRegistration. and apps can access it via the import.

Apps:

```js
import ENV from '<app-name>/config/environment'

// ...
ENV.MY_ENV_VAR
```

Addons:

```js
getOwner(this).resolveRegistration('config:environment').MY_ENV_VAR;
```